# What's the relationship between the Flutter SpriteWidget and the Apple SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm learning the one  https://github.com/spritewidget/spritewidget
who's name is related to the Apple SpriteKit https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/

So do they related in framework design ?

Answer (score 0):

Both SpriteWidget and SpriteKit are loosely inspired by Cocos2D, therefore they have a similar design. A small graphic bitmap that you move around the screen is widely know as a [sprite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics)), that is where the name comes from.